# Using IMPORT instead of LOAD in DB2

Tags: import, load, db2

I wanted to prepare a load utility to load the data into DB2 table. The table has columns which contains GENERATEDALWAYS feature set.

So, I am not able to load an unloaded details from the table.

Is it possible to use import for tables having columns with GENERATEDALWAYS set?

Steps I did:

```
1. db2 "export to tbl.txt of del modified by coldel| select * from <schema.table> where col=value"
2. db2 "delete from <schema.table> where col=value"
3. db2 "import from tbl.txt of del modified by coldel| allow write access warningcount1 insert into <schema.table>"
```

The columns with "GENERATEDALWAYS" is having NEW Value after import. Is it possible to use import to populate GENERATEDALWAYS columns to have the old values?

Appreciate the assistance.

Thanks,
Mathew Liju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible.  With `IMPORT` you can't override columns that have `GENERATED ALWAYS`.  As @Peter Miehle suggests you could alter the table to specify that the column is `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`, but this may break other applications.

Your question's title implies that you don't want to use the `LOAD` utility (but you don't mention anything about it in the actual question).  However, `LOAD` is the only way to write data into the table and maintain the values for the generated column as they exist in the file:

```
db2 "load from tbl.txt of del modified by generatedoverride insert into schema.table"
```

If you do this, be aware that:

- DB2 does not check if there are conflicts with existing rows in the table.  You would need to define a unique index on the column(s) in question to resolve this; this would cause DB2 to delete the rows that you just loaded in the `DELETE` phase of the load.
- If your generated column(s) are using `IDENTITY`, make sure that you alter the column to ensure that future generated values do not conflict with the rows that you just inserted into the table.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can drop the "generation" from the column and add it after importing with the appropriate values again.

Answer (score 0):

@Ian Bjorhovde  has given you the options.

IMPORT actually does INSERTs in the background - ie, it first prepares a INSERT statement with parameter markers and uses the values in the input file for those markers.

In your SQL snapshot you will see  INSERT  statement that is used.

Anything that is not possible in an INSERT statement isn't possible with IMPORT (kind of .. )